# Vanilla Js onclick assignment within dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, onclick

I wish to dynamically create a row of 4 buttons with an .onclick function within dynamically created div. This works perfectly well within a single div, however when attempting to create the buttons inside the nested div, only the buttons created in last div are functioning properly.

I have found questions relating to using var in for loops creating issues, but this doesn't seem to be the case here. I've tried assigning a separate function to .onclick to no avail, and just need to get it sorted!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="entries">
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<script>
let synth = window.speechSynthesis;

let createButton = function (pCat, index, phraseDivIndex) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = pCat[index];
    button.className = "entry";

    button.onclick = function () {
        synth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("boo")); //speak phrase from json
    }
        document.getElementsByClassName("phraseDiv")[phraseDivIndex].appendChild(button); //adds buttons to newly created div for focus management.
}


let populateEntries = function () {
    let phraseDivIndex = -1;
    let pCat = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five","six","seven","eight","nine"];
    for (let i = 0; i < pCat.length; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            phraseDivIndex++;
            document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML += "<div class=phraseDiv tabindex = 0 class = 'catRow'></div>";
        }
        createButton(pCat, i, phraseDivIndex);
    }
}

//create buttons
populateEntries()

</script>
```

Outcome of code:
Only the last row of buttons created have an .onclick event attached to them. That is a problem!

*edit: array index

Comment: Poor technique. `.innerHTML +=` requires a DOM read and write. Store that in a `var results = '';` that you `results += 'innerHTMLCodeHere';` then `Element.innerHTML = results;`. Of course, I don't even recommend `.innerHTML` to create DOM Elements most of the time, since they have to be added to the DOM before you can attach Events to them.  `document.createElement(tag)` is how to create... then it's like `Element.className = 'class1 class2 class3'; Element.tabIndex = -1;` and the like. `Element.onclick = funciton(){ /* do stuff */ }; OtherElement.appendChild(Element)`. Just advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your case is actually a really tricky one. Let me explain though why your event listeners disappear.

The problem lies in this line:

```
document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML += "<div class=phraseDiv tabindex = 0 class = 'catRow'></div>";
```

What happens when you use `innerHTML` in combination with `+=` is the string of `innerHTML` is accessed and then concatenated with whatever you define.

You defined the `onclick` handler as a DOM element property (read more about attributes vs properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)) and these are not included when you access the elements via `innerHTML` and concatenate them with another HTML string. What happens is that you're removing the `onclick` properties every 4th round because they won't be stringified.

What you could do to fix this is not use `=+` with `innerHTML` but rather `appendChild` which keeps the DOM intact.

```
if (i % 4 == 0) {
  phraseDivIndex++;
  const newContainer = document.createElement('div');
  newContainer.classList.add('phraseDiv', 'catRow');
  newContainer.tabIndex = 0;

  document.getElementById("entries").appendChild(newContainer)
}
```

You can find a running version [here](https://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/BXxGdq?editors=1010). Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you for the great explanation and the further references.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about a live event listener. You can create it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const button = e.target.closest('button')

  if (button) {
       synth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("boo"));
  }
})
```

Also, calling `document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML +=` for every iteration is very imperformant. Append to a string instead (the button too, best using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) and set `innerHTML` in the end.